# When I start a process on my computer, I see a file descriptor number 6 open, what is that descriptor for/about?

Tags: command-line, console, file-descriptors

Today I noticed I was getting an error from a tool which verifies its file descriptors on startup. The fact is that I get an extra `pts` connection:

```
# In one console I start `cat`
linux $ cat >/tmp/test

# In another console I search for `cat`'s process ID
linux $ ps -ef | grep cat
alexis   34462 25012  0 11:58 pts/17   00:00:00 cat

# Now check the file descriptors:
linux $ ls -l /proc/34462/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 alexis alexis 64 Sep 23 11:59 0 -> /dev/pts/17
l-wx------ 1 alexis alexis 64 Sep 23 11:59 1 -> /tmp/test
lrwx------ 1 alexis alexis 64 Sep 23 11:59 2 -> /dev/pts/17
lrwx------ 1 alexis alexis 64 Sep 23 11:59 6 -> /dev/pts/17
```

As we can see, `stdin` was set to the destination filename `/tmp/test`. As expected 0 and 2 are set to a `pts`.

What is 6, though?

I am thinking that maybe it comes from my rails environment. The `rvm` script does some "magic" to my console and when I `cd` into a directory with a file named `Gemfile`, it detects it. That being said, I thought that was just a `cd` alias... Anything else could add such a file descriptor to my command lines? What could I do to test where this comes from and what capability it offers?

---

Update: I can confirm that if I open a new console after I comment out the RVM initialization (`. ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm .`) then I don't get that extra pseudo terminal file descriptor. I'm still wondering how can they do that?

Comment: When the program open a file, it get a new file description. Just 0, 1, and 2 are standard. You should check source code of cat, or trace system calls to see what it is 6.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, in case you don't know, `cat` is a system command and it never gets a file descriptor 6 by default (you can create one, though, with `6>blah.log` for example). I tested on one of my VPS to make sure before asking my question.

Comment: I'm not sure about your comment (and yes, I know what it is `cat`). My assumptions are about reading `gettext` file, for localization, but if you check the source, cat is no more the cat of "C Language book"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM opens a new file descriptor to whatever standard error is currently connected to when it starts. Thus, in an RVM environment, file descriptor 6 is the RVM log output. This way RVM can log to the same place by writing output to file descriptor 6, regardless of whether standard error has been redirected.

The file descriptor is opened [at the end of `scripts/functions/logging`](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/1.29.10/scripts/functions/logging#L248).

> ```
> exec 6>&2
> ```

The [`exec`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exec) builtin without an argument, but with a redirection, performs the redirection inside the shell process. Thus `exec 6>&2` opens file descriptor 6 to whatever file descriptor 2 in the shell. Programs that are started from the shell inherit this file descriptor.

When RVM wants to log something, it (usually) outputs to file descriptor 6. This happens in [the `rvm_error` function](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/1.29.10/scripts/functions/logging#L164), for example.

For example, the following code is executed in an RVM environment started from a terminal, it writes “Stuff happened” to `myfile.log`, but writes `Hello` to the terminal.

```
f () {
  …
  echo >&2 "Stuff happened"
  rvm_error "Hello"
}
f 2>myfile.log
```

Comment: Amazing what we can do in a Unix shell!

Answer (score 1):

That special file contains the current thread futex context handle.